# $\max \{\sum \limits_{i=1}^n z_i w_i \}$ where $\sum \limits_{j=1}^n |w_j| = 1$

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

How can we find $\max \{\sum \limits_{i=1}^n z_i w_i  \}$ where $\sum \limits_{i=1}^n |w_j| = 1$? $z, w \in \mathbb{R}^n$

Comment: what's condition on the $z's$?

Comment: Sorry, mistype: it must have been an absolute sum of w's. z is any vector. Answer should be, as far as I can see, $\max \limits_{1 \le i \le n} z_i$ but I cannot prove it

Comment: $z_i$'s are real or complex?

Comment: z are real numbers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that $|\sum_{i=1}^{n}z_iw_i| \leq \sum_{i=1}^{n}|z_iw_i| \leq (max_{i}|z_i|) \sum_{i=1}^{n}|w_i|=(max_{i}|z_i|)$.

So you maximum is less than or equal to $(max_{i}|z_i|) $. Now can you find a seq of $w_i$'s which achieve the maximum?

Comment: How would you prove though that this is the maximum? Why couldn't I find a value bigger than $max_i |z_i|$?

Comment: @trembik: Because of the inequality I proved above. Replace each $|z_i|$ by $max_i|z_i|$.

Comment: Sorry, that was a stupid question. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Voldemort's answer is right and I've upvoted it... however...

This is not actually convex as written. To make it so you must write it this way:
$$\begin{array}{ll}
\text{maximize} & \sum_i z_i w_i \\
\text{subject to} & \sum_i |w_i| \leq 1
\end{array}$$
Fortunately, you can prove this is equivalent. To see why, suppose that you have found an optimal $w^*$ satisfying $\sum_i |w_i^*|=\alpha<1$. If $\sum_i z_i w_i^* > 0$, then $\alpha^{-1} w^*$ will give a larger objective value of $\alpha^{-1} \sum_i z_i w_i^*$, a contradiction. (This isn't quite complete; you'd need to show that the objective has to be nonnegative, and address the zero case explicitly.)

Furthermore, this is actually an instance of [Hölder's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder%27s_inequality), a generalization of the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality:
$$z^Tw\leq \|z\|_p \|w\|_q \qquad \forall~p,q\in[1,+\infty],~1/p+1/q=1$$
In this case, $p=\infty$ and $q=1$. In fact, this can be generalized to *any* dual pair of norms:
$$\langle z, w \rangle \leq \|z\|\|w\|_*$$
In this case, $\|z\|\triangleq\|z\|_\infty$ and $\|w\|_*=\|w\|_1$. To be fair, this definition is a bit circular, since the dual norm is defined by
$$\|w\|_* \triangleq \max_{z:~\|z\|\leq 1} \langle z, w \rangle$$
which puts us right back to your question. (Who knows, perhaps that's exactly why you asked it! :-))

Comment: My question was motivated by my attempts to prove that infinity norm is a dual of L1 norm :)